# Node js deployed files is not reflecting Azure WebApps

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I have an web app running on azure with node js. Deployed some changes to the appservice. Also verified the changes in using kudu console. js file changes are already there. But nodejs app is still serving the previous api implementation.

I resterted the app service, still no luck.

Comment: Did you notice any abnormalities in the app service logs when you restarted your web app?

Comment: Ok, I forgot after posting here. Not sure how, but somehow the node module installed on app service server got corrupted and node modules were not getting installed. I cleared npm cache and reinstalled node modules and then it started working.